# How to run commands in cmd [elevated] using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I want to run elevated command, *for example* `calc.exe` in cmd using PowerShell. I've tried from PowerShell:

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd calc.exe
```

All it does is opening the elevated cmd, but does not run `calc.exe` (command).

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The executable invoked by `Start-Process` is `cmd`; you must specify its *arguments* separately, via the `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter, as an *array* (`,`-separated):

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd -Args /k, calc.exe
```

<sup>Note: The arguments happen not to need *quoting* here, but `-`-prefixed arguments or arguments with embedded spaces do; quoting is always an option (`'/k', 'calc.exe'`)</sup>

Note:

- `/k` is required to keep the `cmd` console window open after launching `calc.exe` (`/c` would close it right after, but in that case you could just skip `cmd` and pass `calc.exe` directly to `Start-Process`).
- Generally, you need *either* `/c` or `/k` in order to pass a command to execute to `cmd`; without that, an argument such as `calc.exe` is simply *ignored*.
  Run `cmd /?` for more information.